# Insert objects into array sequentially over multiple calls

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm adding new photos to my database in groups as they are uploaded to Instagram. Say my first call to the Instagram API returns 5 photo objects in an array, `[20,21,22,23,24]`. `20` being the most recent and `24` the oldest. Then my next call several minutes later returns 5 newer photo objects, `[15,16,17,18,19]`. `15` being the most recent and `19` the "oldest" (but always newer than `20`), and on and on.

Ideally I would like my database to store the objects as `[15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]` or `[24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15]`. However, if I use `push` I end up with: `[20,21,22,23,24,15,16,17,18,19]`, while if I use `unshift` I end up with: `[19,18,17,16,15,24,23,22,21,20,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to reverse your original arrays.

Demo:

```
var x = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24];
var y = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
var pushed = [];
var unshifted = [];
var i;


for(i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    pushed.push(x[i]);
    unshifted.unshift(x[i]);
} 

for(i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    pushed.push(y[i]);
    unshifted.unshift(y[i]);
}

console.log(pushed); // outputs [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15]
console.log(unshifted); // outputs [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```